# Elasticsearch similarity discount_overlaps

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.3.1 and I'm evaluating BM25 and Classic TF/IDF.
I came across the `discount_overlaps` property which is optional.

> Determines whether overlap tokens (Tokens with 0 position increment)
>   are ignored when computing norm. By default this is true, meaning
>   overlap tokens do not count when computing norms.

Can someone explain what the above means with an example if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the norm is calculated as `boost / √length`, and this value is stored at index time. This causes matches on shorter fields to get a higher score (because 1 in 10 is generally a better match than 1 in 1000).

For an example, let's say we have a synonym filter on our analyzer, that is going index a bunch of synonyms in the indexed form of our field. Then we index this text:

> The man threw a frisbee

Once the analyzer adds all the synonyms to the field, it looks like this:
[image: post-analysis graph]

Now when we search for "The dude pitched a disc", we'll get a match.

The question is, for the purposes the norm calculation above, what is the length?

- if discount_overlaps = false, then length = 12
- if discount_overlaps = true, then length = 5

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you have any links so I can read more about this? I don't mind if it's part of a book too (I can buy it)

Comment: Is there a query to find the length value?